# Academic Documents Attestation in London

Tags: united-kingdom

I am an Indian citizen and I recently got an admit from one of the universities in France and to complete the admission process, the school requires my undergraduate mark sheets. The hard copy of the mark sheets has to be officially certified. Where can I get it done in London?

Comment: Has the school requiring the hard copy mark sheets given any advice on the type of individual/entity acceptable to them? Is the purpose to certify copies or to certify the contents? Possibly the university where you completed your undergraduate studies can help?

Comment: "Has the school requiring the hard copy mark sheets given any advice on the type of individual/entity acceptable to them?" : They have not mentioned that.   "Is the purpose to certify copies or to certify the contents?" : I guess more to do with the authenticity of the documents.   " Possibly the university where you completed your undergraduate studies can help? " : Already talked to them and they can do that but the process takes around 20 days and I don't have that much time.